# How to convert a vector of enums into a vector of inner values of a specific variant of that enum

Tags: rust, iteration, pattern-matching

The following code example is the best that I have come up with so far:

```rust
enum Variant {
    VariantA(u64),
    VariantB(f64),
}

fn main() {
    let my_vec = vec![Variant::VariantA(1),
                      Variant::VariantB(-2.0),
                      Variant::VariantA(4),
                      Variant::VariantA(3),
                      Variant::VariantA(2),
                      Variant::VariantB(1.0)];

    let my_u64_vec = my_vec
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|el| match el {
            Variant::VariantA(inner) => Some(inner),
            _ => None,
        })
        .collect::<Vec<u64>>();

    println!("my_u64_vec = {:?}", my_u64_vec);
}
```

I would like to know if there is a less verbose way of obtaining the vector of inner values (i.e., Vec<u64> in the example). It feels like I might be able to use something like `try_from` or `try_into` to make this less verbose, but I cannot quite get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums are not "special" and don't have much if any implicitly associated magic, so by default yes you need a full match -- or at least an `if let` e.g.

```rust
if let Variant::VariantA(inner) = el { Some(inner) } else { None }
```

*However* nothing prevents you from implementing whatever utility methods you're thinking of on your enum e.g. `get_a` which would return an `Option<A>` (similar to `Result::ok` and `Result::err`), or indeed to implement `TryFrom` on it:

```rust
use std::convert::{TryFrom, TryInto};

enum Variant {
    VariantA(u64),
    VariantB(f64),
}

impl TryFrom<Variant> for u64 {
    type Error = ();

    fn try_from(value: Variant) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if let Variant::VariantA(v) = value { Ok(v) } else { Err(()) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_vec = vec![Variant::VariantA(1),
                      Variant::VariantB(-2.0),
                      Variant::VariantA(4),
                      Variant::VariantA(3),
                      Variant::VariantA(2),
                      Variant::VariantB(1.0)];

    let my_u64_vec = my_vec
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|el| el.try_into().ok())
        .collect::<Vec<u64>>();

    println!("my_u64_vec = {:?}", my_u64_vec);
}
```

Comment: Yep, I suspected that I was going to have to implement a trait over my enum if I wanted something less verbose